# Driver Manager ODBC error when attempting to write to Vertica

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, vertica

I'm attempting to write to a Vertica database using SQLAlchemy.

I've created my engine as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sclalchemy_vertica
engine = create_engine('vertica+pyodbc://username:password@127.0.0.1:9223/DB')
df.to_sql('some_table', engine)
```

where df is a pandas dataframe with some data. However, upon attempting to write, I get the following error:

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Vertica' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

anyone know what this might be about? I am on Mac OS X.

Comment: Could you share your `odbcinst.ini` and `vertica.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up unixODBC for Vertica is a bit of manual effort.  You have to:

1. set up `odbcinst.ini`
2. set up `vertica.ini` (maybe only Linux?)
3. set up `odbc.ini`
4. export `VERTICAINI` (maybe only Linux?)

I would look at the following:

[Installing ODBC on Mac OSX](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/InstallingDrivers/InstallingTheODBCDriverOnMacintoshOSX.htm%3FTocPath%3DConnecting%2520to%2520HP%2520Vertica%7CClient%2520Libraries%7CInstalling%2520the%2520%2520Client%2520Drivers%7CInstalling%2520the%2520Client%2520Drivers%7C_____8)

[Creating odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/InstallingDrivers/CreatingAnODBCDSNForMacintoshOSXClients.htm) 
[Additional settings for Linux](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientODBC/LocationOfTheAdditionalDriverSettings.htm) 
(Not sure if you need the last one or not, it's listed as Linux but I would look at it anyhow)